# Launch libgdx project on HTML 5 based browser platform

Tags: libgdx

I want to launch my Libgdx project on HTML 5 platform but there is Error like

The type com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   GwtLauncher.java    /Digestive-System-html/src/com/me/mygdxgame/client

The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint. Fix the build path then try building this project   Digestive-System-html

I googled but unable to resolve this problem. Any help wiil appreciated

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Hello vishal to my knowledge if you go through this you can setup libgdx project on HTML 5 based browser platform.As of version 0.9.3, libgdx comes with an easy to use application called "Libgdx Setup".The following steps will create everything needed to develop for the desktop, android, html 5.

Download the gdx-setup-ui.jar from http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/gdx-setup-ui.jar. The jar is also contained in all stable and nightly releases.
Execute the jar by double clicking it or from the command line via java -jar gdx-setup-ui.jar

Specify your project's configuration (Configuration Panel).Specify the libgdx stable/nightly release zip file or press one of the buttons to download the latest stable/nightly release (Library Selection Panel).

Hit the "Generate projects" button (Generation Panel)
Open Eclipse and import the generated projects into your workspace.

File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace
Click "Browse", select the folder containing the generated projects.
Make sure all the projects are checked, then click "Finish"

To fix the error of the HTML5 platform, go to the "Problems" view, right click the error message "The GWT SDK JAR gwt-servlet.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory" and select "Quick Fix".

Click "Finish".